# UnsatisfiedDependencyException when using Hibernate with H2 database in Spring Core Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'categoryDAO' defined in
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'getCategoryDao' parameter 0:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index; Exception
>   in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'categoryDAO' defined in
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'getCategoryDao' parameter 0:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
>     at com.niit.shoppingcart.CategoryTest.main(CategoryTest.java:13)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean
>   instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>     ... 13 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1106)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:774)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
>     at
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig.getSessionFactory(ApplicationContextConfig.java:56)
>     at
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$449f4899.CGLIB$getSessionFactory$1()
>     at
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$449f4899$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c760c88.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
>     at
>   com.niit.shoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$449f4899.getSessionFactory()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>     ... 28 more

**This is ApplicationContextConfig.java file**

```
 package com.niit.shoppingcart.config;

    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


    import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.CategoryDAO;
    import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.CategoryDAOImpl;
    import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.Category;
    import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.Product;
    import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.Supplier;
    import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.UserDetails;


    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.niit.shoppingcart")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class ApplicationContextConfig {

        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test");
            dataSource.setUsername("sa");
            dataSource.setPassword("");

            return dataSource;
        }


        private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            return properties;
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
            LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
            sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
            sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(Category.class);
            sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(Supplier.class);
            sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(UserDetails.class);
            sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(Product.class);
            return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
        public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
                SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
                    sessionFactory);

            return transactionManager;
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean(name = "categoryDAO")
        public CategoryDAO getCategorDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            return new CategoryDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
        }
    }
```

**This is the java test file in which the exception is occurring**

```
package com.niit.shoppingcart;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.CategoryDAO;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.Category;

public class CategoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.niit.shoppingcart");
        context.refresh();
        CategoryDAO categoryDAO = (CategoryDAO) context.getBean("categoryDAO");

        Category category = (Category) context.getBean("category");

        category.setC_id("cg1234");
        category.setC_name("phone");
        category.setC_desc("This is the first category");

        if (categoryDAO.save(category) == true) {
            System.out.println("Category created");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unable to create category");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The test class isn't really loading the Spring Boot context properly. All you are doing is loading the beans based on the package you are scanning which is `com.niit.shoppingcart`. If you want to "test" your application the way you are doing it I would recommend something like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public class CategoryTest implements ApplicationRunner {
        private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;

        // Spring Boot 1.4 autowires on constructors automatically
        public CategoryTest(CategoryDAO categoryDAO) {
            this.categoryDAO= categoryDAO;
        }

        public void run(String[] args) {
            // This doesn't need to be a bean as it is just a pojo state object
            Category category = new Category();
            category.setC_id("cg1234");
            category.setC_name("phone");
            category.setC_desc("This is the first category");

            if (categoryDAO.save(category) == true) {
                System.out.println("Category created");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unable to create category");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The better approach is to use JUnit to do your testing. Here is how the code would look as a JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CategoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;

    @Test
    public testSave() {
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setC_id("cg1234");
        category.setC_name("phone");
        category.setC_desc("This is the first category");

        assertThat(categoryDAO.save(category)).isTrue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but, it threw the same exceptions and more on running.